# Django datetime.datetime to Decimal is not supported migrations

Tags: python, django, postgresql, database-migration

Below is the model and the error that is coming up when I try to migrate. I am using django 1.10 and my database is empty when I try to migrate.

**Model:**

```
from django.db import models

class OrderEntry(models.Model):
    quote_num = models.CharField(max_length=50, primary_key=True)
    customer = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    cust_po = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    pdf = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=True, null=True)

class Items(models.Model):
    quote_num = models.CharField(max_length=50, primary_key=True)
    item_1 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    item_2 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    item_3 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    item_4 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    item_5 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    item_6 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    item_7 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    item_8 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    item_9 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    item_10 = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class ItemDetails(models.Model):
    item = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True)
    quote_num = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    quan = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    desc = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0, null=True)
```

**Error:**

```
C:\Users\Evan\Desktop\webapp>py manage.py migrate 
Operations to perform:
Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, orders, sessions

Running migrations:
  Applying orders.0013_itemdetails_price...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Evan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Evan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 359, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Evan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 294, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\Evan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 345, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Evan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 204, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "C:\Users\Evan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 115, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\Evan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 145, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\Evan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 244, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "C:\Users\Evan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 129, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "C:\Users\Evan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py", line 84, in database_forwards
    field,
  File "C:\Users\Evan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\schema.py", line 21, in add_field
    super(DatabaseSchemaEditor, self).add_field(model, field)
  File "C:\Users\Evan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 395, in add_field
    definition, params = self.column_sql(model, field, include_default=True)
  File "C:\Users\Evan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 147, in column_sql
    default_value = self.effective_default(field)
  File "C:\Users\Evan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 221, in effective_default
    default = field.get_db_prep_save(default, self.connection)
  File "C:\Users\Evan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1583, in get_db_prep_save
    return connection.ops.adapt_decimalfield_value(self.to_python(value), self.max_digits, self.decimal_places)
  File "C:\Users\Evan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1554, in to_python
    return decimal.Decimal(value)
TypeError: conversion from datetime.datetime to Decimal is not supported
```

I have set some defaults and null values to try to migrate to a postgre database. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error message leads me to believe that you have mistakenly set the price field to be a DateTimeField and now you are trying to change it. that is consistent with the error you get if you try to execute a statement like this in the psql console.

```
ALTER TABLE item_details ALTER COLUMN price SET TYPE DECIMAL
```

In order to fix it, delete the newly created migration. Then drop the price column (prices saved as datetime if any surely will not be usefull). Then ./manage.py makemigrations followed by ./manage.py migrate.

After this completes sucessfully, add the price field back in but this time as decimal.

Comment: I deleted the migration, and dropped the price and datetime field from my models. However, I get the same error when both those fields don't exist.

Comment: deleting the migration means deleting the .py file as well as the .pyc file